# Browsing the files on a webserver with php

Tags: php, webserver, file-browser

Is there a way to browse and the get the path to files that are on a web server using php...? Possibly any jquery plugin to accomplish this....? Or else how can i do this using only php...??

Edit : I've found some scripts that run as stand alone on the webserver and let you browse the file structure.. But i need to know the method with which it is done so that i can implement it in my own script....

Thanks a lot for your suggestions....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explore the server's filesystem you'll need the [directory functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dir.php):

> - [chdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) — Change directory
> - [chroot](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chroot.php) — Change the root directory
> - [dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) — Return an instance of the Directory class
> - [closedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) — Close directory handle
> - [getcwd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) — Gets the current working directory
> - [opendir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) — Open directory handle
> - [readdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) — Read entry from directory handle
> - [rewinddir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) — Rewind directory handle
> - [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) — List files and directories inside the specified path

But if you're looking for some code to read through, that does what it seems you're looking for, check out [filebrowser](http://thefilebrowser.com/). No longer in active development, if I remember correctly it's pretty simple code at the core.

Comment: filebrowser is a pretty good script.... Too bad support has been discontinued....

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you have a look at the code for **[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)**'s file manager.

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)'s the PHP filesystem reference

Comment: Isn't that a text editor..? I need to know how i can browse the file structure on a web server...

Comment: Sorry.. my head just isn't clear today..!! i know these functions but just can't figure out how i can use them to  access the server's directory structure...